# How to properly use char negation [^ ] to do word non-fixed width backward lookbehind?

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to match all Python source code lines which has an open parenthesis, but it is not a function definition. Basically, match all function calls, but not function definitions.

I am parsing Python Source Code, but I have only the PCRE engine, not the new Javascript with non fixed width look-behind. I am trying to not match if the sentence is preceded by the word `def` anywhere  (`.*`) before the match.

This regular expression does it half ways:

```
(?:^)(?:[^d][^e][^f])+\(
```

It should not match lines with: (not match an open parenthesis preceded by def)

```
anything def anything(thing)
anyyything def anythinggg(thing)
```

And only match lines as: (match an open parenthesis preceded by anything but def)

```
anything anything(thing)
anyyything anythinggg(thing)
```

But it has a problem, as I do `(?:[^d][^e][^f])+`, the expression only works when the open parenthesis `(` is preceded by a sentence which has length  multiple of 3:

[image] [image]

1. https://regex101.com/r/ec0FgD/1 - Live example

Comment: I am parsing Python source code with PCRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PCRE you cannot use variable length lookbehind but can make use of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs to fail a match:

```
def[^(]*\((*SKIP)(*F)|\(
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ec0FgD/2)

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.

Answer (score 0):

> It should not match lines with: (not match an open parenthesis preceded by def)

You can use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion at `^` start of each line to check for your condition:

```
^(?![^\n(]*?def)[^\n(]*\(
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5ZmCVX/1/)

- the [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\n(]` matches any character besides newline and opening parenthesis
- to discard the part before `(` from match, use [`\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) for reset: [`^(?![^\n(]*?def)[^\n(]*+\K\(`](https://regex101.com/r/5ZmCVX/2)
- use [word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at start/end of `def` if it's desired to match the substring  as word

Comment: Who downvoted, please give hint, what's wrong with my answer, that I can improve. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps they were just jealous? Thanks, for sharing an alternative!